# sometimes I get "this file contains potentially unsafe dynamic content" message in Mathematica notebook

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Sometimes, when I open my own notebook, I get the message:

> This file contains potentially unsafe dynamic content.

I do not remember when I started seeing these messages, but it was not long ago. May be 2-3 weeks ago? They do not show all the time. It is my own notebook, that I could close, go sleep, wake up, come open it up again, and I could see the above message, or I could not. Not sure what triggers it.

Here is a screen shot of one just happened.

[image]

I normally just ignore it, and enable dynamics and go on. I googled around, and do not see mention of it. One reference I found is [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NotebookSecurity.html), where it talks about `TrustedPath` and such, and I really could not understand it at all.

This notebook just sits in my folder on my PC, same folder it was on all the time. May be an expert can explain this in easy to understand way, because I do not understand why I need to worry about the  trustedPath thing when I am working on my own local PC (I am not even on a network, just stand alone PC in my living room) and what I need to change if any.

I'm using v8.0.1 on windows.

Comment: Mathematica does not know if the file was downloaded or authored locally, so it warns you about dynamic execution. It does so because `Dynamic` might contain code which accesses file systems, and even sends out emails (see `SendMail`). I, personally, do not bother with trusted path, and simply ignore the warning when it comes up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My comments assume V8 of Mathematica...

For any given notebook, the message appears the first time an expression is about to be evaluated automatically, in some way other than normal user-directed input cell evaluation.  So-called dynamic constructs like `Manipulate`, `Dynamic` and `Hyperlink` have the potential of causing such evaluations.  The warning message is just a way to ensure that user remains in control.

**Sometimes No Warning?**

As will be shown in the examples below, the message does not appear until the dynamic code is about to be triggered (e.g. by bringing a `Manipulate` into view or by hovering a `Hyperlink`).  This is why, in the same notebook, you might sometimes see the message and sometimes not.

***Manipulate*** Example

I see from the screenshot that the notebook in question is a Wolfram Demonstrations Project authoring notebook.  It almost certainly contains a `Manipulate` expression that triggers the message.

Here is a way to cause the warning to appear:

1. From the menu, choose *File / New / Demonstration*
2. Scroll down to the manipulate section and change the expression to `Manipulate[Plot[Sin[x y], {x, -1, 1}], {y, -1, 1}]` -- but **do not evaluate the cell**.
3. Save and close the notebook
4. Re-open the notebook, but note that the warning message does not appear.
5. Evaluate the `Manipulate` cell.
6. Save and close the notebook.
7. Re-open the notebook and note that warning message now appears (provided the manipulate section is visible -- if not, scroll down to see it).

The first time the notebook was re-opened, it did not contain a cell with dynamic content.  But when the `Manipulate` cell was evaluated, that changed.  Thus, on subsequent re-openings the warning message appeared.

***Hyperlink*** Example

All of this true for even seemingly innocuous content, like hyperlinks.  Try this:

1. Create a regular notebook and evaluate a cell containing the expression `Hyperlink["http://www.wolfram.com"]`.
2. Save, close and re-open the notebook.
3. Hover over the hyperlink to make the warning message appear.

It appears that WRI is taking a very conservative view about dynamic content.  I, for one, applaud that policy.  Mathematica presents a *huge* attack surface for malicious code, so a conservative approach is good in my opinion.  (In fact, the new plug-in scares me a little on that score, but that's another story.)

**Warning Settings**

You can tweak the settings related to the warning message by looking at the *Notebook Security* section on the *System* tab of the *Preferences* dialog.

Comment: What new plug-in do you mean, and why?

Comment: @Mr Wizard, I am sure WReach is talking about the new CDF plugin, you know the one that can now run Mathematica demos inside the browser. I call them now Mathematica applets, since at my school no one knows anything about Mathematica, so I tell them it is an applet, then they would understand. The new CDF plugin page:
http://www.wolfram.com/cdf-player/plugin/success.html

I really like this very much. I write all my school HWs now as applets. Now more static images, Mathematica applets are the way to go.
--Nasser

Comment: @Mr.Wizard @Nasser Indeed, I am referring to the CDF browser plug-in.  I fear the same sort of security holes that have plagued Javascript, Flash, Reader, Java and so on.  I wonder how much security analysis went into packaging the kernel as a plug-in?  We shall see whether the CDF player becomes a target and, if it does, how WRI responds.

Comment: For the record, however, I think that the CDF player is really cool, and I just *love* the idea of Mathematica notebooks being as widely accepted as PDFs...

Comment: There was some recent discussion on CDF plugin, its use, etc.. at the Mathematica walkingrandomly blog, here is the link

http://www.walkingrandomly.com/?p=3323

Only thing I wish, is that Mathematica applets would also support InputField[], which would make the applet much more useful. (but may be less secure?) but with Java applets, one can enter text to the applet. InputField[] would allow one to write much more flexible Mathematica applets.
--Nasser

Answer (score 7):

Mathematica notebooks can execute arbitrary code simply by virtue of opening the file.  This code could be potentially malicious, and it can be very difficult to predict what the code will actually do prior to executing it.

When you open a notebook Mathematica doesn't know whether you are the original author of the notebook (and you trust the content to run automatically), or whether you downloaded a notebook from the website of a complete stranger (and you shouldn't trust the content to run automatically).  The best guess Mathematica can make is based on the location of the file on your computer.  Certain directories are trusted (i.e. the Mathematica installation directory) and other directories are untrusted (i.e. your web browser download folder and your email attachments folder).  The settings that control which directories are trusted and which are untrusted are described in the documentation page you mentioned.

In your case what's probably happening is that your document is saved in your Desktop directory or some other directory which is untrusted and Mathematica is asking your permission before doing something it thinks may be potentially harmful.  Since you know it is not harmful then you are safe to allow the Dynamic content.

If you do not want to see these warnings in the future you can do one of two things:

- Move the notebook file to a directory that is trusted.
- Remove the notebook's current directory from the list of untrusted directories specified by the UntrustedPath option.

Comment: Thanks, but when you say "In your case what's probably happening is that your document is saved in your Desktop directory or some other directory which is untrusted", as I said, this is not the case. The notebook is in the SAME folder it always was. I edited it before many times, close it an open it many times from the same folder. do not get this error. Sometimes I do, for no reason I can think of.

Comment: I too see this happen more often recently. I'm not sure about directories that were involved, so I'll  keep an eye on that. Might it be related to the CDF player? I installed it a couple of weeks ago.

Comment: @Nasser, an explanation of this would be if you have only recently added some dynamic content (e.g. a `Manipulate`) to your notebook.