# Why do I get security warning message "This file contains potentially unsafe dynamic content" in this construct

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am finally able to reproduce this message that I get once in a while.

This in on V8.04, on windows 7.

While trying things, I found how to make Mathematica generate the above message when I open a notebook with Manipulate in it.

First the error message screen:

[image]

I now hit 'enable dynamics' and all seems well. But each time I reopen the notebook, I get the message again.  (One must close M, and start up again, and then open the notebook to see the message).

So I do not understand this warning message, and why it comes up, and what I need to change in the code to remove it.

The code to generate it is:

```
Manipulate[

  DynamicModule[{p},
   p["x"] = 0;
   Row[{Dynamic[
      Refresh[p["x"]++; Row[{"p[x]=", p["x"]}],
       TrackedSymbols -> {n}]]}]
   ],

  Button["update counter", n++],
  {{n,0}, None}
  ]
```

The above is on its own notebook, with nothing else in the notebook.

I close M, then start it, then open the notebook, and I see the above message.

Now, I thought initially that to remove the message, I need to change p["x"] to p[x] so I closed the above notebook, and made a new notebook with this code:

```
Manipulate[

  DynamicModule[{p},
   p = 0;
   Row[{Dynamic[Refresh[p++; Row[{"p=", p}], TrackedSymbols -> {n}]]}]
   ],

  Button["update counter", n++],
  {{n, 0}, None}
  ]
```

Then closed M, and started it again, and opened the above notebook,
and now I *did not* see the warning message. But when I repeated the process, I saw the same error come back.

(I posted this question to the Math group, but that is slow, and my post has not even shown up there, but in that post I said that the error went away when I changed p["x"] to p[x], because it actually did at first, but when I later tried it, the message came back, which I do not understand why)

p["x"] is an indexed object as explained in this page:

http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/MakingDefinitionsForIndexedObjects.html

**The question is: What is in the above code makes this warning to show up? Am I writing something wrong in the above example?**

Code runs OK after I enable dynamics. Btw, I am opening this notebook from the same folder I open all my other notebooks, nothing changed and this is on home PC, no networks share folder and nothing out of the ordinary.

Here is the related link to notebook security

http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NotebookSecurity.html

I do not see in the above anything related to what I am doing. All what I can say, it has to do with the use of DynamicModule[] inside Manipulate, which is itself a DynamicModule. But I do not understand this well enough to figure why this is a problem.

**Update 1**

I do not see how this has anything to do with path.  I can remove the error by simply commenting out the inner Dynamic like this:

```
Manipulate[


 (*
   DynamicModule[{p},
   p["x"]=0;
   Row[{Dynamic[Refresh[p["x"]++;Row[{"p[x]=",p["x"]}],TrackedSymbols-> \
   {n}]]}]
   ],
 *)

 n,
 Button["update counter", n++],
 {{n, 0}, None}
 ]
```

Save the notebook, close M, start M, open the notebook. Error went away.

So, it is in the code.

**Update 2**

Trying to reproduce what Yoda reported in his answer, I am not able to.

1. make new notebook, type `Dynamic@DateString[]`
2. ENTER to evaluate.
3. SAVE
4. close M
5. open M
6. open notebook
7. no error

[image]

**Update dec 21, 2001**

On the Math Group, John Fultz was kind enough to reply to my post, I do not think he will mind if I post his answer here for the benefit of others to see

```
> > So, why is using p["x"] causing the security warning message?

That is a bug, which has already been fixed in development sources.
John Fultz
User Interface Group
Wolfram Research, Inc.
```

Sorry that I do not have a link to include to his reply, I could not find a link on google now. I use thunderbird to read newsgroups.

Should now this question remain open? Or should it be closed? If I need to close it, I can accept one of the answers so it is closed.

Comment: I don't think it's because of the code. It's most likely because your working directory is not a "trusted" path... I believe "trusted", by default, only includes directories created by mma.

Comment: @yoda, folder I use for the above is my home folder, I use for all other notebooks. Nothing changed. Do you get this error on your end?

Comment: Definitely a trusted path issue. Best solution to ensure you never have this problem is to run some code that David Reiss posted in Mathgroup. Do a search for his name and trusted path and you should find it.

Comment: How can it be a trusted issue? I simply remove the inner dynamic, close the notebook, restart everything, and the error message goes away. Same notebook, same folder. I changed only the code. Please see edit

Comment: similar question: [sometimes I get “this file contains potentially unsafe dynamic content” message in Mathematica notebook](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6144049/211232)

Comment: @NasserM.Abbasi It's Dynamic content that has the potential to be harmful, and as a result this check is run (and the warning) only when you have Dynamic content (i.e., the Notebook tries to automatically run something as soon as you open)

Comment: @WReach, thanks for the link, I forgot about that one. But at least this one has a code which generate the error, may be this helps.

Comment: @NasserM.Abbasi You can add John's answer as an answer below and accept it (when you can).

Answer (score 3):

This is not because of the particular code sample, but rather due to Mathematica's security features. From [`tutorial/NotebookSecurity`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NotebookSecurity.html),

> When the user opens a notebook containing dynamic content, Mathematica
>   will first determine whether the notebook's directory is trusted,
>   untrusted, or neither.
>
> - If the notebook's directory is trusted, the notebook will be allowed to automatically perform dynamic evaluations without alerting
>     the user.
> - If the notebook's directory is untrusted, the user will be alerted upon any attempt by the notebook to perform dynamic evaluations.
>     [image]

By default, only `$InstallationDirectory`, `$BaseDirectory`, and `$UserBaseDirectory` are "trusted". In addition, there are a set of directories that are *always* untrusted (can be changed). These are your downloads
The solution now, is to add your current working directory to the list of trusted folders.

Go to `Preferences > Advanced > Open Options Inspector` and under `Global Preferences`, start searching for `trusted` and you should see the three options pop up. You can add them here.

[image]

Comment: Ok but before I do that and break something, what I do not understand is why I have to do this now? I use Manipulate and Dynamics all the time. Manipulate is DynamicModule[].  So why do I have to add my folder path now? I have been using Dynamics and Manipulate all this time with no problem? Never had to do this. Does any one here really add each folder they have a notebook in it which uses Manipulate or any dynamics to the trusted path each time? Thanks.

Comment: @NasserM.Abbasi I don't work with Manipulate and Dynamic all that much, and usually it is only for answering SO questions or trying out others' answers. As such, all these are in notebooks that are eventually killed, so I've never had to face this issue then. I've seen this happen in the few times I've used it legitimately, but I know why it happens and simply Enable it and move on. Never had to see it enough number of times to annoy me...

Comment: so is the key phrase in all of this is "Dynamic content that has the potential to be harmful," ??  So, what is it in my code above that I showed that has the  potential to be harmful? Again, I use Manipulate all the time. So it is NOT just the use of any Dynamics that is the problem, but certain type of use. So the question is, what is it in the above code which can be harmful?

Comment: sorry but that does not help me. Again, I used DyanamicModule before directly, I made a CDF with Dynamics directly, and never seen this message. Manipulate itself is DynamicModule, and I am sure many here did the same. So, there are some Dynamic constructs that make M complain. If we, the users do not know what these are, then how is one to know if what they are writing is safe or not? Try the code, and if the message show up, try something else? Is this the way it is supposed for one to write software? Trial and error?

Comment: @NasserM.Abbasi The error comes up when there is _any_ `Dynamic` stuff in the output cell. Start a fresh nb and try `Dynamic@DateString[]` and execute. Now save, close and reopen. You should see the warning. Delete the output cell, save, close and reopen. You won't get the warning because the Input cell is inert. Now execute again and delete the input cell, leaving the output intact. Save, close and reopen, you should get the warning again, because now the output cell has a Dynamic in it that tries to run something, which mma doesn't know if it could be harmful or not.

Comment: I just tried what you said, few times, and I am NOT gettting any error messages. I even closed M, start it, opened the notebook, and no error message. Please see screen shot.  Could you please show a screen shot on your version with the error message? May be I misunderstood something. Thanks

Comment: and what OS, M version you have? may be this makes a difference? Thanks

Comment: I also tried your second case: "Now execute again and delete the input cell, leaving the output intact. Save, close and reopen, you should get the warning again" and again, I get no error/warning messages of any sort. And  I have Evaluation->Dynamic update enabled ON all the time ofcourse.

Comment: @NassarM.Abbasi if you have dynamic content in an *output* cell AND your notebook is not in a trusted directory, you will always get this message. That is the upshot as per Yoda's comments. If you do not see that message then the NotebookDirectory[] must be a trusted path.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch, but it is the SAME folder! My folder can NOT be in the trusted path one second and then next second not be in the trusted path? Which is it? I am using the same folder for everything I do. At first you said I got the error because my notebook was NOT in trusted path. Now you say i am not getting the error because my folder IS in the trusted path?? It is the same NotebookDirectory[] each time. I still do not understand the problem. Thanks

Comment: @NassarM.Abbasi If you try save, close M (not just the file), and then reopen, it should behave like abcd is saying. The trick is to close Mathematica FrontEnd, which will disable the `Evaluation->Dynamic update enabled`. By default this is disabled for every FrontEnd session for untrusted locations. You can enable it for every session either in the menu or clicking on the message that pops up. To avoid doing this every time add your directory to trusted in Option inspector. Adding your path to the trusted list as a string "" is fine. Enabling TrustByDefault might break something one day.

Answer (score 3):

This is more a continuation of Yoda's answer plus the comments than a separate stand alone answer but as has been stated if you open a notebook from an untrusted directory **and** you have Dynamic content in an Output cell you will get a security warning. If you evaluate the following code:

```
CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, {"NotebookSecurityOptions", "TrustedPath"}]

CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, {"NotebookSecurityOptions", "UntrustedPath"}]

NotebookDirectory[]
```

you will be able to satisfy yourself about whether or not your notebook is in a trusted or untrusted path (notwithstanding the appearance or not of the security warning).

Comment: +1, thanks for the commands, they help. I tried them and the folder I am using is NOT in the trusted path. So the question remain, why I do not get the error message using the example shown by Yoda? (the DateString example) ? I'll show the output of the commands if that helps, but my NotebookDirectoy[] did not show up on the trusted path for sure.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are using the default option settings (i.e. "TrustByDefault"->Automatic) you will see one of three behaviors.

- If the notebook is in a directory listed in the "TrustedPath" the content is assumed to be safe and you will never see the warning.
- If the notebook is in a directory listed in the "UntrustedPath" the content is assumed to be unsafe and you will always see the warning.
- If the notebook is in a directory that is listed in neither the "TrustedPath" nor the "UntrustedPath" you may or may not see the warning depending on the contents of the DynamicBox expression stored in the notebook.  Mathematica will examine the expression before attempting to evaluate it.  If it contains only expressions from a short whitelist of "safe" expressions then you will not see the warning.  If it contains any expressions which are not included in the whitelist of "safe" expressions then you will see the warning.

Comment: I think one of Nasser's questions in the midst of everything else, is "what is the whitelist of safe expressions". Is there such a list? I thought it applied to _all_ expressions in the output cell that had Dynamic. Even a notebook with `Dynamic@1` (evaluated, with the output cell) gives me the warning.

Comment: +1 for the extra info, my folder is on NEITHER the trusted nor the untrusted. I will have to make now some tries, and see if I add the folder explicitly on the untrusted path, if I now get the error from the Yoda example (DateString example). Will update later... may be we getting close to the bottom of this mystery :)

Comment: Worth noting that in CDFs the security warning seems to be more fickle. I had a security "problem" with a CDF and the solution -- provided by Wolfram -- was to eliminate DownValues, i.e. rewrite my function as a pure function.

Comment: @yoda - YOU'RE IN LUCK... I seem to recall coming across such a list during a recent troll through some MMA install files. (digging, digging) You'll need to find a file called MiscExpressions.tr, which on my machine is located at C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\8.0\SystemFiles\FrontEnd\TextResources. All sorts of frontend resources and goodies are defined in here. Scroll to the end of the file, looking for things like `@@resource DangerousSymbols`, `@@resource SafeContexts`, and `@@resource SafeExpressions`. May have saved other lists like this, but can't find ATM. Of interest?

Answer (score 2):

I too had a problem with this message coming up on notebooks that I thought it hadn't come up on before, but I am now convinced it is because of Dynamic output existing in the notebook and the fact that Dynamic output runs in the front end. So when you open a notebook with Dynamic output visible the FE will try to run it. If you delete all Dynamic output from a notebook, save it, close it (and even close and reopen Mathematica to be sure) then reopen the notebook the message should not appear since there is no Dynamic output.

I did as yoda suggested, I opened the Option Inspector and edited the TrustedPath in the Global Preferences. I am posting this "answer" as a continuation of yoda's answer since I had to do some playing to figure out exactly how to add a path to TrustedPath.

I added Documents as a trusted path as follows (on Mac OS 10.6) (and I am careful not to save anything there I don't trust):

1. Click on the little edit button to the left of the Value column for TrustedPath.
2. Click on Add in the window that opens.
3. You will be presented with

   FrontEnd`FileName[{$RootDirectory},"x"]
4. Replace x with the path that you want trusted such as:

   FrontEnd`FileName[{$RootDirectory}, "/Users/John/Documents/"]

Now I never get the annoying warning for notebooks stored in Documents or any of its subfolders.